# How to change the result of the select statement on sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT        tbl_varsity_2.idnumber AS IDNUMBER, CONCAT(tbl_varsity_2.firstname, ' ', tbl_varsity_2.middlename, '. ', tbl_varsity_2.lastname) AS NAME, 
                         COALESCE(tbl_attendance_2.login, { d '0000-00-00 00:00:00' }) AS LOGIN, COALESCE(tbl_attendance_2.logout, { d '0000-00-00 00:00:00' }) AS LOGOUT, 
                         tbl_attendance_2.totaltime AS TOTALTIME, tbl_varsity_2.sport AS SPORT FROM            tbl_varsity tbl_varsity_2 LEFT JOIN
                         tbl_attendance tbl_attendance_2 ON tbl_varsity_2.idnumber = tbl_attendance_2.idnumber WHERE (tbl_varsity_2.status = 'active') AND(tbl_varsity_2.idnumber != ALL (SELECT tbl_varsity_5.idnumber FROM tbl_varsity tbl_varsity_5  INNER JOIN tbl_attendance tbl_attendance_5 ON tbl_varsity_5.idnumber=tbl_attendance_5.idnumber WHERE (tbl_attendance_5.login BETWEEN '2012-11-23 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 00:00:00') AND (tbl_varsity_5.status='active')))
```

RESULT is
10169060  Shee-Ann G. Dela Cruz      `2012-11-27 09:07:53  2012-11-27 14:08:03`  <*i want to change this value to [0000-00-00 00:00:00]>*            Table Tennis Women  123456    Kevin S. Juanico            `0000-00-00 00:00:00  0000-00-00 00:00:00`             Badminton Men       12692070  Charie May C. Cudiamat      0000-00-00 00:00:00  0000-00-00 00:00:00             Basketball Women

so that all value will be 0000-00-00 00:00:00

please help

Answer (score 0):

if you want the `0000-00-00 00:00:00` value to be displayed on all records (since you didn't specify any condition), just use it on your select statement:

```
SELECT tbl_varsity_2.idnumber AS IDNUMBER
    , CONCAT(tbl_varsity_2.firstname, ' ', tbl_varsity_2.middlename, '. ', tbl_varsity_2.lastname) AS NAME
    /*, COALESCE(tbl_attendance_2.login, { d '0000-00-00 00:00:00' }) AS LOGIN
    , COALESCE(tbl_attendance_2.logout, { d '0000-00-00 00:00:00' }) AS LOGOUT*/
    , '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AS LOGIN
    , '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AS LOGOUT
    , tbl_attendance_2.totaltime AS TOTALTIME
    , tbl_varsity_2.sport AS SPORT 
    FROM tbl_varsity tbl_varsity_2 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_attendance tbl_attendance_2 ON tbl_varsity_2.idnumber = tbl_attendance_2.idnumber 
    WHERE (tbl_varsity_2.status = 'active') 
        AND (tbl_varsity_2.idnumber != ALL (
                SELECT tbl_varsity_5.idnumber 
                    FROM tbl_varsity tbl_varsity_5  
                    INNER JOIN tbl_attendance tbl_attendance_5 ON tbl_varsity_5.idnumber=tbl_attendance_5.idnumber 
                    WHERE (tbl_attendance_5.login BETWEEN '2012-11-23 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 00:00:00') 
                        AND (tbl_varsity_5.status='active')
                )
            )
```